# Django view returning count of users based on last_login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mysql

I have a Django application where I have a view that returns the count of the users who did login today. Corresponding statement is as follows:

```
login_count= User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()
```

I want to get the count of users who did login once in the last week and last the month. Like, here `timezone.now()` returns today's date, is there anything like range which will cover a week or a month?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is, and [its even named `range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#range).

Example

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
User.objects.filter(last_login__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Of for the last week

```
today = datetime.date.today()
last_week = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
User.objects.filter(last_login__range=(last_week, today))
```

However,

> Filtering a DateTimeField with dates won’t include items on the last day, because the bounds are interpreted as “0am on the given date”. If pub_date was a DateTimeField, the above expression would be turned into this SQL:

A quick solution would be to simply add a day, so the `date` range includes up to the last minute *of today*, but not more (also update `last_week`).

```
today = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
last_week = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
User.objects.filter(last_login__range=(last_week, today))
```

Comment: Okay great! But now start_date and end_date are hard coded. It is something which will be called everyday, so start_date could be datetime.date(timezone.now().date()). How can I extend it for end_date?

Comment: Is timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7) the correct direction?

Comment: Yes, correct. Had also just added it to the answer.

Comment: However, there is one problem, login_count returns me 2 as 2 users logged in today and the query in answer returns me 0, ideally this also should return 2 as today is still part of the week. can  datetime.date.today() be converted to  timezone.now().date()?

Comment: Added to my answer